# How to check from which satellites gps receives data?

Tags: android, listener, android-sensors, android-gps

I wrote listener which is getting data from sensor gps(like lon lat etc).
I wrote listener which is getting GNSSStatus and calculate constalation.
But now how can i know from which constalation(galileo/gps/glonas/...)?
I can't use update flag in one listener to gain data from second couse when screen is off that work bad secondary when it can't be sure from which satelite current i took data on listener onLocationChanged(first listener).

So how can i merge that for get information from what constalation get data.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of what you have.